# Dummy numpy array with all equal values for fast __getitem__

Tags: python, numpy

In my code I have a large 2D array from where, inside a double `for`-loop, I extract an element at the time.

Now, there are situations where the values inside this matrix are all equal. I'm trying to create a "dummy"-array that, when sliced, always returns the same value without actually performing the `__getitem__` operation that would be a useless waste of time.

A possible inelegant solution could be to use a `lambda` function and replace the `__getitem__` with a `__call__`. Something like:

```
if <values are all equal>:
    x = lambda i,j : x0
else:
    x = lambda i,j : x_values[i,j]
```

Then I'd need to replace `x[i,j]` with `x(i,j)` inside the code, that would look to something like:

```
for i in range(max_i):
    for j in range(max_j):
        ...
        x(i,j)
        ...
```

I find this, however, somehow un-intuitive to read and somehow cumbersome. The thing that I dislike the most is replacing `x[i,j]` with `x(i,j)` as it is less intuitive to understand that `x(i,j)` is a sort of slicing and not a real function.

Another solution could be to code a class like:

```
class constant_array:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __getitem__(self, _)
        return self.val
```

Another issue with both this and the previous method is that `x` would no longer be a `numpy.array`. So calls like `np.mean(x)` would fail.

Is there a better way to create an object that when sliced with `x[i,j]` always return a constant value independently from `i` and `j` without having to change all the following code?

Comment: "*`__getitem__` operation that would be a useless waste of time*" `__getitem__` on an array/list is O(1), Did you profile your code? Any attempt to hack around it will only **increase** the overhead

Comment: Yes, but this specific line does not appear in the profiler, but it's incorporated into the "local time" of the parent function. Maybe I'm just trying to optimize the wrong line of code

Comment: Anyway, all you have to do is create a subclass that overrides `__getitem__`, and if `item` is a slice, do whatever you want

Comment: @DeepSpace I know subclassing `np.array` can be difficult (https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.subclassing.html). I was trying to avoid it, but maybe it's just the only way of doing this